# java.sql.SQLException: - ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am getting an ORA-01000 SQL exception. So I have some queries related to it.

1. Are maximum open cursors exactly related to number of JDBC connections, or are they also related to the statement and resultset objects we have created for a single connection ? (We are using pool of connections)
2. Is there a way to configure the number of statement/resultset objects in the database (like connections) ?
3. Is it advisable to use instance variable statement/resultset object instead of method local statement/resultset object in a single threaded environment ?
4. Does executing a prepared statement in a loop cause this issue ? (Of course, I could have used sqlBatch) Note: pStmt is closed once loop is over.

   ```
   { //method try starts  
     String sql = "INSERT into TblName (col1, col2) VALUES(?, ?)";
     pStmt = obj.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
     pStmt.setLong(1, subscriberID);
     for (String language : additionalLangs) {
       pStmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(language));
       pStmt.execute();
     }
   } //method/try ends

   { //finally starts
      pStmt.close()
   } //finally ends
   ```
5. What will happen if conn.createStatement() and conn.prepareStatement(sql) are called multiple times on single connection object ?

**Edit1:** 
6. Will the use of Weak/Soft reference statement object help in preventing the leakage ?

**Edit2:** 
 1. Is there any way, I can find all the missing "statement.close()"s in my project ? I understand it is not a memory leak. But I need to find a statement reference (where close() is not performed) eligible for garbage collection ? Any tool available ? Or do I have to analyze it manually ?

Please help me understand it.

### Solution

### To find the opened cursor in Oracle DB for username -VELU

Go to ORACLE machine and start sqlplus as sysdba.

```
[oracle@db01 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Then run

```
SELECT   A.VALUE,
    S.USERNAME,
    S.SID,
    S.SERIAL#
  FROM V$SESSTAT A,
    V$STATNAME B,
    V$SESSION S
  WHERE A.STATISTIC# = B.STATISTIC#
    AND S.SID        = A.SID
    AND B.NAME       = 'opened cursors current'
    AND USERNAME     = 'VELU';
```

If possible please read [my answer for more understanding of my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397716/146325)

Comment: Can you post your complete code? It would be interesting to see where are you closing the opening braces opened for `for (String language : additionalLangs) {`

Comment: @ Kanagavelu Sugumar : why not ask 5 different questions in SO?

Comment: Here's a response I found very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4507507/501113

Comment: Please see if the answer is useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716456/spring-storedprocedure-with-oracle-array-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-excee/35080509#35080509

Comment: For tracking down open cursors in Oracle, you might also want to take a look at the `SYS.V$OPEN_CURSOR` view. This will give you not only the SID, but also the SQL text.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

ORA-01000, the maximum-open-cursors error, is an extremely common error in Oracle database development. In the context of Java, it happens when the application attempts to open more ResultSets than there are configured cursors on a database instance.

Common causes are:

1. Configuration mistake

   - You have more threads in your application querying the database than cursors on the DB. One case is where you have a connection and thread pool larger than the number of cursors on the database.
   - You have many developers or applications connected to the same DB instance (which will probably include many schemas) and together you are using too many connections.
   - **Solution:**

     - [Increasing the number of cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2583309/1395668) on the database (if resources allow) or
     - Decreasing the number of threads in the application.
2. Cursor leak

   - The applications is not closing ResultSets (in JDBC) or cursors (in stored procedures on the database)
   - **Solution**: Cursor leaks are bugs; increasing the number of cursors on the DB simply delays the inevitable failure. Leaks can be found using [static code analysis](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), [JDBC](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) or application-level logging, and [database monitoring](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html).

### Background

This section describes some of the theory behind cursors and how JDBC should be used. If you don't need to know the background, you can skip this and go straight to 'Eliminating Leaks'.

#### What is a cursor?

A cursor is a resource on the database that holds the state of a query, specifically the position where a reader is in a ResultSet. Each SELECT statement has a cursor, and PL/SQL stored procedures can open and use as many cursors as they require. You can find out more about cursors on [Orafaq](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Cursor).

A database instance typically serves several different *schemas*, many different *users* each with *multiple sessions*. To do this, it has a fixed number of cursors available for all schemas, users and sessions. When all cursors are open (in use) and request comes in that requires a new cursor, the request fails with an ORA-010000 error.

#### Finding and setting the number of cursors

The number is normally configured by the DBA on installation. The number of cursors currently in use, the maximum number and the configuration can be accessed in the Administrator functions in [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html). From SQL it can be set with:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET OPEN_CURSORS=1337 SID='*' SCOPE=BOTH;
```

#### Relating JDBC in the JVM to cursors on the DB

The JDBC objects below are tightly coupled to the following database concepts:

- JDBC *Connection* is the client representation of a database *session* and provides database *transactions*. A connection can have only a single transaction open at any one time (but transactions can be nested)
- A JDBC *ResultSet* is supported by a single *cursor* on the database. When close() is called on the ResultSet, the cursor is released.
- A JDBC *CallableStatement* invokes a *stored procedure* on the database, often written in PL/SQL. The stored procedure can create zero or more cursors, and can return a cursor as a JDBC ResultSet.

JDBC is thread safe: It is quite OK to pass the various JDBC objects between threads.

For example, you can create the connection in one thread; another thread can use this connection to create a PreparedStatement and a third thread can process the result set. The single major restriction is that you cannot have more than one ResultSet open on a single PreparedStatement at any time. See [Does Oracle DB support multiple (parallel) operations per connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947316/does-oracle-db-support-multiple-parallel-operations-per-connection)

Note that a database commit occurs on a Connection, and so all DML (INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE's) on that connection will commit together. Therefore, if you want to support multiple transactions at the same time, you must have at least one Connection for each concurrent Transaction.

#### Closing JDBC objects

A typical example of executing a ResultSet is:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
try {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT FULL_NAME FROM EMP" );
    try {
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            System.out.println( "Name: " + rs.getString("FULL_NAME") );
        }
    } finally {
        try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) { }
    }
} finally {
    try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) { }
}
```

Note how the finally clause ignores any exception raised by the close():

- If you simply close the ResultSet without the try {} catch {}, it might fail and prevent the Statement being closed
- We want to allow any exception raised in the body of the try to propagate to the caller. 
  If you have a loop over, for example, creating and executing Statements, remember to close each Statement within the loop.

In Java 7, Oracle has introduced the [AutoCloseable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) which replaces most of the Java 6 boilerplate with some nice syntactic sugar.

#### Holding JDBC objects

JDBC objects can be safely held in local variables, object instance and class members. It is generally better practice to:

- Use object instance or class members to hold JDBC objects that are reused multiple times over a longer period, such as Connections and PreparedStatements
- Use local variables for ResultSets since these are obtained, looped over and then closed typically within the scope of a single function.

There is, however, one exception: If you are using EJBs, or a Servlet/JSP container, you have to follow a strict threading model:

- Only the Application Server creates threads (with which it handles incoming requests)
- Only the Application Server creates connections (which you obtain from the connection pool)
- When saving values (state) between calls, you have to be very careful. Never store values in your own caches or static members - this is not safe across clusters and other weird conditions, and the Application Server may do terrible things to your data. Instead use stateful beans or a database.
- In particular, *never* hold JDBC objects (Connections, ResultSets, PreparedStatements, etc) over different remote invocations - let the Application Server manage this. The Application Server not only provides a connection pool, it also caches your PreparedStatements.

### Eliminating leaks

There are a number of processes and tools available for helping detect and eliminating JDBC leaks:

1. During development - catching bugs early is by far the best approach:

   1. Development practices: Good development practices should reduce the number of bugs in your software before it leaves the developer's desk. Specific practices include:

      1. [Pair programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming), to educate those without sufficient experience
      2. [Code reviews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) because many eyes are better than one
      3. [Unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) which means you can exercise any and all of your code base from a test tool which makes reproducing leaks trivial
      4. Use [existing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0) for connection pooling rather than building your own
   2. Static Code Analysis: Use a tool like the excellent [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to perform a static code analysis. This picks up many places where the close() has not been correctly handled. Findbugs has a plugin for Eclipse, but it also runs standalone for one-offs, has integrations into Jenkins CI and other build tools
2. At runtime:

   1. Holdability and commit

      1. If the ResultSet holdability is ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT, then the ResultSet is closed when the Connection.commit() method is called. This can be set using Connection.setHoldability() or by using the overloaded Connection.createStatement() method.
   2. Logging at runtime.

      1. Put good log statements in your code. These should be clear and understandable so the customer, support staff and teammates can understand without training. They should be terse and include printing the state/internal values of key variables and attributes so that you can trace processing logic. Good logging is fundamental to debugging applications, especially those that have been deployed.
      2. You can add a debugging JDBC driver to your project (for debugging - don't actually deploy it). One example (I have not used it) is [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/). You then need to do some simple analysis on this file to see which executes don't have a corresponding close. Counting the open and closes should highlight if there is a potential problem

         3. Monitoring the database. Monitor your running application using the tools such as the SQL Developer 'Monitor SQL' function or [Quest's TOAD](http://www.quest.com/toad/). Monitoring is described in [this article](http://www.orafaq.com/node/758). During monitoring, you query the open cursors (eg from table v$sesstat) and review their SQL. If the number of cursors is increasing, and (most importantly) becoming dominated by one identical SQL statement, you know you have a leak with that SQL. Search your code and review.

### Other thoughts

#### Can you use WeakReferences to handle closing connections?

Weak and soft references are ways of allowing you to reference an object in a way that allows the JVM to garbage collect the referent at any time it deems fit (assuming there are no strong reference chains to that object).

If you pass a ReferenceQueue in the constructor to the soft or weak Reference, the object is placed in the ReferenceQueue when the object is GC'ed when it occurs (if it occurs at all). With this approach, you can interact with the object's finalization and you could close or finalize the object at that moment.

Phantom references are a bit weirder; their purpose is only to control finalization, but you can never get a reference to the original object, so it's going to be hard to call the close() method on it.

However, it is rarely a good idea to attempt to control when the GC is run (Weak, Soft and PhantomReferences let you know *after the fact* that the object is enqueued for GC). In fact, if the amount of memory in the JVM is large (eg -Xmx2000m) you might *never* GC the object, and you will still experience the ORA-01000. If the JVM memory is small relative to your program's requirements, you may find that the ResultSet and PreparedStatement objects are GCed immediately after creation (before you can read from them), which will likely fail your program.

**TL;DR:** The weak reference mechanism is not a good way to manage and close Statement and ResultSet objects.

Comment: If you create statements in a loop, make sure it is closed in the loop else you will end up closing only the last statement.

Comment: Thanks, basiljames. Just edited the answer to add in the point you made.

Comment: @ Andrew Alcock Thanks a lot! Andrew. Could you please answer the 6th also.

Comment: @AndrewAlcock Please.. please.. please.. answer my 7th question also. Since our project we are facing ORA-01000 very frequently while load testing. Your inputs are more valuable for me. Thanks a ton in advance!!

Comment: RE: 7 - you can try proximity searching using a tool such as grep. When you recognize a SQL (select, insert, update, delete), see the proximity of the word close() next to the statement. If the proximity is further away than expected, that might be a way to investigate where it is missing. http://www.lightboxtechnologies.com/2012/07/27/proximity-searching-with-grep/

Comment: Don't forget to also close the preparedStatement, e.g. `resultSet.getStatement().close()`

Comment: First off, great answer. Second, does closing the statement close the result set and free up the cursor? In our existing code it's easy to insure all statements are closed so is that sufficient?

Comment: @DavidThielen - "does closing the statement close the result set and free up the cursor?" - yes. If all ResultSets are closed after use you will not have a cursor leak (You may still have a problem with the max number of cursors if the design of the application uses ResultSet objects for extended durations - which is entirely possible for some heavyweight client-server apps like Toad. Imagine one user with 100 tabs open, each with one ResultSet in it that is being paged through).

Answer (score 31):

I am adding few more understanding.

1. Cursor is only about a statement objecct; It is neither resultSet nor the connection object.
2. But still we have to close the resultset to free some oracle memory. Still if you don't close the resultset that won't be counted for CURSORS.
3. Closing Statement object will automatically close resultset object too.
4. Cursor will be created for all the SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement.
5. Each ORACLE DB instance can be identified using oracle SID; similarly ORACLE DB can identify each connection using connection SID. Both SID are different.
6. So ORACLE session is nothing but a jdbc(tcp) connection; which is nothing but one SID.
7. If we set maximum cursors as 500 then it is only for one JDBC session/connection/SID.
8. So we can have many JDBC connection with its respective no of cursors (statements).
9. Once the JVM is terminated all the connections/cursors will be closed, OR  JDBCConnection is closed CURSORS with respect to that connection will be closed.

**Loggin as sysdba.**

In Putty (Oracle login):

```
  [oracle@db01 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

In SqlPlus:

UserName:  `sys as sysdba`

### Set session_cached_cursors value to 0 so that it wont have closed cursors.

```
 alter session set session_cached_cursors=0
 select * from V$PARAMETER where name='session_cached_cursors'
```

### Select existing OPEN_CURSORS valuse set per connection in DB

```
 SELECT max(a.value) as highest_open_cur, p.value as max_open_cur FROM v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$parameter p WHERE a.statistic# = b.statistic# AND b.name = 'opened cursors current' AND p.name= 'open_cursors'  GROUP BY p.value;
```

### Below is the query to find the SID/connections list with open cursor values.

```
 SELECT a.value, s.username, s.sid, s.serial#
 FROM v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s
 WHERE a.statistic# = b.statistic#  AND s.sid=a.sid 
 AND b.name = 'opened cursors current' AND username = 'SCHEMA_NAME_IN_CAPS'
```

### Use the below query to identify the sql's in the open cursors

```
 SELECT oc.sql_text, s.sid 
 FROM v$open_cursor oc, v$session s
 WHERE OC.sid = S.sid
 AND s.sid=1604
 AND OC.USER_NAME ='SCHEMA_NAME_IN_CAPS'
```

Now debug the Code and Enjoy!!! :)

Comment: Here is another query that seems to work well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2560415/32453

Answer (score 5):

Correct your Code like this:

```
try
{ //method try starts  
  String sql = "INSERT into TblName (col1, col2) VALUES(?, ?)";
  pStmt = obj.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
  pStmt.setLong(1, subscriberID);
  for (String language : additionalLangs) {
    pStmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(language));
    pStmt.execute();
  }
} //method/try ends
finally
{ //finally starts
   pStmt.close()
}
```

**Are you sure, that you're really closing your pStatements, connections and results?**

To analyze open objects you can implment a delegator pattern, which wraps code around your statemant, connection and result objects. So you'll see, if an object will successfully closed.

An Example for: pStmt = obj.**getConnection**().prepareStatement(sql);

```
    class obj{ 

    public Connection getConnection(){
    return new ConnectionDelegator(...here create your connection object and put it into ...);

    } 
}


class ConnectionDelegator implements Connection{
    Connection delegates;

    public ConnectionDelegator(Connection con){
       this.delegates = con;
    }

    public Statement prepareStatement(String sql){
        return delegates.prepareStatement(sql);
    }

    public void close(){
        try{
           delegates.close();
        }finally{
           log.debug(delegates.toString() + " was closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your application is a Java EE application running on Oracle WebLogic as the application server, a possible cause for this issue is the [Statement Cache Size](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13737/ds_tuning.htm#i1193250) setting in WebLogic.

If the Statement Cache Size setting for a particular data source is about equal to, or greater than, the Oracle database maximum open cursor count setting, then all of the open cursors can be consumed by cached SQL statements that are held open by WebLogic, resulting in the ORA-01000 error.

To address this, reduce the Statement Cache Size setting for each WebLogic datasource that points to the Oracle database to be significantly less than the maximum cursor count setting on the database.

In the WebLogic 10 Admin Console, the Statement Cache Size setting for each data source can be found at Services (left nav) > Data Sources > (individual data source) > Connection Pool tab.

Comment: Hibernate has a Statement cache too.  See also https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-PlatformSpecificIssues#jive_content_id_After_a_while_Oracle_throws_this_exception_too_many_open_cursors

Answer (score 3):

I too had faced this issue.The below exception used to come

```
java.sql.SQLException: - ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
```

I was using **Spring Framework** with **Spring JDBC** for dao layer.

My application used to leak cursors somehow and after few minutes or so, It used to give me this exception.

After a lot of thorough debugging and analysis, I found that there was the problem with the **Indexing, Primary Key and Unique Constraints** in one of the **Table** being used in the **Query** i was executing.

My application was trying to update the **Columns** which were mistakenly **Indexed**.
So, whenever my application was hitting the update query on the indexed columns, The database was trying to do the reindexing based on the updated values. It was leaking the **cursors**.

I was able to solve the problem by doing Proper Indexing on the columns  which were used to search in the query and applying appropriate constraints wherever required.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem (ORA-01000) today. I had a for loop in the try{}, to execute a SELECT statement in an Oracle DB many times, (each time changing a parameter), and in the finally{} I had my code to close Resultset, PreparedStatement and Connection as usual. But as soon as I reached a specific amount of loops (1000) I got the Oracle error about too many open cursors.

Based on the post by Andrew Alcock above, I made changes so that **inside** the loop, I closed each resultset and each statement after getting the data and before looping again, and that solved the problem.

Additionaly, the exact same problem occured in another loop of Insert Statements, in another Oracle DB (ORA-01000), this time after 300 statements. Again it was solved in the same way, so either the PreparedStatement or the ResultSet or both, count as open cursors until they are closed.

Comment: This doesn't seem right.  Spring documents that it is responsible for closing ResultSets ( https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc ).

Comment: just for clarification, in those examples I wasn't using Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set autocommit=true? If not try this:

```
{ //method try starts  
    String sql = "INSERT into TblName (col1, col2) VALUES(?, ?)";
    Connection conn = obj.getConnection()
    pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    for (String language : additionalLangs) {
        pStmt.setLong(1, subscriberID);
        pStmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(language));
        pStmt.execute();
        conn.commit();
    }
} //method/try ends { 
    //finally starts
    pStmt.close()
} //finally ends
```

Comment: Could you please answer the other questions as well?

Comment: Autocommit doesn't close connections - it only automatically commits each statement immediately after execution. If you are using autocommit you are not getting value from one of the database's most important properties - transactions. You might consider using a NoSQL DB instead.

Answer (score 1):

query to find  sql that opened.

```
SELECT s.machine, oc.user_name, oc.sql_text, count(1) 
FROM v$open_cursor oc, v$session s
WHERE oc.sid = s.sid
and S.USERNAME='XXXX'
GROUP BY user_name, sql_text, machine
HAVING COUNT(1) > 2
ORDER BY count(1) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem mainly happens when you are using connection pooling because when you close connection that connection go back to the connection pool and all cursor associated with that connection never get closed as the connection to database is still open.
So one alternative is to decrease the idle connection time of connections in pool, so may whenever connection sits idle in connection for say 10 sec , connection to database will get closed and new connection created to put in pool.

Answer (score 0):

Using batch processing will result in less overhead. See the following link for examples:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we were using Hibernate and we had many variables referencing the same Hibernate mapped entity. We were creating and saving these references in a loop. Each reference opened a cursor and kept it open.

We discovered this by using a [query to check the number of open cursors](http://www.techpaste.com/2012/06/13/steps-solve-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded-issue-weblogic/?doing_wp_cron=1403729247.7885780334472656250000) while running our code, stepping through with a debugger and selectively commenting things out.

As to why each new reference opened another cursor - the entity in question had collections of other entities mapped to it and I think this had something to do with it (perhaps not just this alone but in combination with how we had configured the fetch mode and cache settings). Hibernate itself has had [bugs around failing to close](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8811) open cursors, though it looks like these have been fixed in later versions.

Since we didn't really need to have so many duplicate references to the same entity anyway, the solution was to stop creating and holding onto all those redundant references. Once we did that the problem when away.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my datasource in WildFly and Tomcat, connecting to a Oracle 10g.

I found that under certain conditions the statement wasn't closed even when the statement.close() was invoked.
The problem was with the Oracle Driver we were using: ojdbc7.jar. This driver is intended for Oracle 12c and 11g, and it seems has some issues when is used with Oracle 10g, so I downgrade to ojdbc5.jar and now everything is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue because I was querying db for more than 1000 iterations.
I have used try and finally in my code. But was still getting error.

To solve this I just logged into oracle db and ran below query:

ALTER SYSTEM SET open_cursors = 8000 SCOPE=BOTH;

And this solved my problem immediately.

Comment: This salved some symptoms but didn't actually solve the problem. You need to fix your code so it closes cursors once it has finished with them.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue after setting the prepared statement cache size to a large value. Apparently, when prepared statements are kept in cache, the cursor stays open.