# Multiple queries on database using jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a text file from where i read values

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:/workspace/table_export.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
String line = null;
while( (line = br.readLine())!= null )
{
        String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        String var_1 = tokens[0];
        System.out.println(var_1);
        getstaffinfo(var_1,connection);
}
```

The values read from text file is passed to  getstaffinfo method to query the db

```
public static String getstaffinfo(String var_1, Connection connection) throws SQLException, Exception
  // Create a statement
   {
   StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
   ResultSet rs = null;
   String record = null;
   Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
   query.delete(0, query.length());
   query.append("select firstname, middlename, lastname from users where employeeid = '"+var_1+"'");
   rs = stmt.executeQuery(query.toString());
       while(rs.next())
       {
   record = rs.getString(1) + " " +
                  rs.getString(2) + " " +
                  rs.getString(3);
  System.out.println(record);
 }
 return record;
}
```

I get almost 14000 values read from text file which is passed to getstaffinfo method, all database activities such has loading driver, establishing connectivity all works fine. But while printing

it throws error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
```

Although i understand that this error is to do with database configuration, Is there an efficent way of making one db call and exceute the query for multiple values read from text file.
Any inputs would be of great use.

Many Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what is resultSet?you have not defined anywhereI think resultSet should be replaced by rs

Comment: I suspect you have a leak in DB Connections / Statements. Make sure they are closed properly when finished.

Comment: @navman I could not understand that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close ResultSet `rs.close();` and Statement `stmt.close();` after your while loop in `getstaffinfo()`, preferably inside a `finally{}`

Comment: Hi Bimalesh, if i add rs.close();
     stmt.close();
     return record; this is not returning the record. The method is called for each value, so it needs to return . Following your advise, i dont get any exxception, but values after querying is not returned. Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Pls modify your question with close() added in the code sample so that we can see what is happening.

Comment: public static String getstaffid(String var_1, Connection connection)
   throws SQLException, Exception
 // Create a statement
 {
  String record = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
  try {
   rs = stmt
     .executeQuery("select firstname, middlename, lastname from globalusers where username = '"
       + var_1 + "'");
   while (rs.next()) {
    record = rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " "
      + rs.getString(3);
    System.out.println(record);
   }
  } finally {
   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
  }
  return record;

 }//Worked fine.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to close resultSet via `rs.close();` and Statement via `stmt.close();`

```
while(rs.next()){
   record = rs.getString(1) + " " +
            rs.getString(2) + " " +
            rs.getString(3);
   System.out.println(record);
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are not `close`ing `ResultSet` and `Statement` (though it is good that your are working on one `Connection`), try closing resources, the error should not happen.

Bigger issue is that if you do close, you are hitting DB `n` number of times where `n` is number of filtering criteria. One solution to this could be make `in` clause instead of `=` selection.
e.g:

Say total lines = N, divide into x chunks hence make N/x `select` statements

For example is N=20000, x=1000; you need to fire 20 `selects` instead of 20000.

Comment: public static String getstaffid(String var_1, Connection connection)
   throws SQLException, Exception
 // Create a statement
 {
  String record = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
  try {
   rs = stmt
     .executeQuery("select firstname, middlename, lastname from globalusers where username = '"
       + var_1 + "'");
   while (rs.next()) {
    record = rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " "
      + rs.getString(3);
    System.out.println(record);
   }
  } finally {
   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
  }
  return record;

 }

Answer (score 0):

close resultset and statement 
like this way

```
rs.close(); stmt.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use `IN` clause in the query and call the method only once.

```
 FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:/workspace/table_export.txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
 String line = null;
 String var_1 = "";
 while( (line = br.readLine())!= null )
 {
    String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
    var_1 = var_1+tokens[0]+",";
    System.out.println(var_1);
}
var_1 = var_1.subString(0,var_1.lastIndexOf(","));
getstaffinfo(var_1,connection);
```

change `getstaffinfo()` like this

```
public static List<String> getstaffinfo(String var_1, Connection connection) throws SQLException, Exception
// Create a statement
{
 StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
 ResultSet rs = null;
 String record = null;
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
 query.delete(0, query.length());
 query.append("select firstname, middlename, lastname from users where employeeid IN ("+var_1+")");
 try{
  rs = stmt.executeQuery(query.toString());
   while(rs.next())
   {
     record = rs.getString(1) + " " +rs.getString(2) + " " +rs.getString(3);
     System.out.println(record);
     list.add(record);
    }
    }finally{
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
    }
    return list;
 }
```

Note : Cant we put more than 1000 values in 'in clause'.
Related links.
1.https://forums.oracle.com/thread/235143?start=0&tstart=0
2.[java.sql.SQLException: - ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192592/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded)