# Maximum Open Cursors Exceeded In SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

I am using SQL Devolopper and I am getting the Max open cursors exceeded. I tried to look it up aswell as solutions but I can't seem to understand it. Can someone please explain to me in detail what the problem is and how it is fixed.

Comment: Perhaps, you have some PL/SQL block which opens a cursor,but never closes it. The error message says all of it. There is a DB parameter which controls the maximum opened cursors at a moment. And this includes all the cursors (implicit and explicit) created in the database across all clients.(jdbc, sqlplus, odbc, toad.. Etc). And [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192592/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded) really has a lot of great solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to close cursors in PL/SQL before you open more cursors. There is limit defined at database level for number of open cursors in the database ( Parameter open_cursor). You may ask your Oracle DBA to increase open_cursor parameter at database level( This will require downtime).