# ORA-01000 - Maximum open cursors exceeded - Spring JDBC 3.2.5

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, oracle11gr2, cursors

we have a Java Enterprise Application running on Weblogic Server 12c
 using **Spring JDBC 3.2.5** to access **Oracle 11gR2** Database.
 In production environment after some time we got this exception:
 **"ORA-01000 - Maximum open cursors exceeded"** and server instance need
 to be restarted; it seems that open cursors increase more and more
 until they reach the maximum threshold set on Oracle. Increasing the
 threshold didn t solve the problem.
 We check the (very large) source code but we didn t find any point
 where we miss closing connection, at the moment; moreover we usually
 don t open and close connections but we use Spring JdbcTemplate to
 handle database interaction.
 Could be a Spring problem? 
 Any hints?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: - ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192592/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug of that version of Spring. update Spring Library

Answer (score 1):

The oracle message **"ORA-01000 - Maximum open cursors exceeded"** can be caused by not closing `PreparedStatement`s or `ResultSet`s. Each `PreparedStatement` or `ResultSet` is a cursor in the Oracle database.

To circumvent this error for the short term you can increase the limit of open cursors in the database (but sooner or later it will occur again).

To circumvent this error really you have to audit the complete application and close all opened `PreparedStatement`s or `ResultSet`s.

Also an intermediate JDBC driver which tracks all `PreparedStatement`s or `ResultSet`s can help to identify the problematic part of the application.

Comment: Thanks but we don t use **PreparedStatement**, we use **Spring JdbcTemplate** *http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) so we don t need to explicity **OPEN** and **CLOSE** connections. Do you have some links for "intermediate JDBC driver" ?

Comment: facing same issue with spring jdbc template. Did you figure out the problem?