# Any alternative to use Oracle cursors with Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

I have parent table and child table, with 1 to 0..N mapping, i.e. one parent record can have 0 or many child records.

Query:

```
select parent_Table.*  , cursor (select * from child_Table child where child.id = parent.id) child_data
from parent_Table parent
```

On the Java side, i am using rowMapper to convert this into POJO of parent and child classes. But here I may get following error, if the number of parent record for which child record exists, exceeds number of allowed open cursors with Oracle.

```
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
```

Is there any alternative to above approach ?

Comment: you could try to change sql to use LEFT JOIN, may be even with analytical function like 'row_number()/count() over(partition by parent.id)' to distinguish parent records.

Comment: most probably you application leaks resources. you can either fix you app or you can use xml to convert child's data into single XML document.

Comment: Maybe read through this for some pointers on why you may be hitting this wall.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192592/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded