# Shiny: Live data using ROracle with invalidateLater -> maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: r, oracle, shiny

I am trying to use Shiny App to display 'live process data' of last 5 minutes.

While leaving the app run, after some time it stops displaying the data (it behaves like there is no data available in database) and in console i can see the Error:

> ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

At the moment i am getting live update using `invalidateLater()`, below is sample code:

```
library(ROracle)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


ui <-  fluidPage(plotOutput("plot", height=800))

server <-  function(input, output, session) {

  con=reactiveValues(cc=NULL)

  drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
  con$cc<- dbConnect(drv,"xxx",username="xx",password="xx")

  observe({
    if(!is.null(con$cc)& is(con$cc,"OraConnection")){ # check if connected
      output$test <- renderText({
        "Verbindung zur Datenbank erfolgreich hergestellt"
      }) 

      sqlOutput <- reactive({
        withProgress(message = 'Processing...',  style = "old", value = 0, 
                     {

                       for (i in 1:10) {
                         incProgress(1/30)
                         Sys.sleep(0.1)
                       }

                       invalidateLater(5000, session) # Invalidates MyData after 5000 millisecs = 5 secs.
                       rs <- dbSendQuery(con$cc, paste("select * from XX where Time >= SYSDATE - 5/(24*60) order by Time asc"))
                       sqlOutput <- fetch(rs)
                       sqlOutput
                     })})

      testplot <- function(){

        g <-ggplot(data=sqlOutput(),aes(x=x, y=x))+ geom_line()  
        g
      }

      output$plot <- renderPlot({testplot()})



    }else if (!is.null(con$cc) ){
      output$test <- renderText({
        con$cc
      })
    }
  })


  session$onSessionEnded(function() { 
    observe({
      if(!is.null(con$cc)& is(con$cc,"OraConnection")){# check if connected
        print(paste0("disconnect ",dbDisconnect(con$cc)))}
    }) 
  })

}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have seen another posts on stackoverflow having same problem, however they are not using R, [rather java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192592/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded).

Additionaly i know that the db user i am using has two connections open to database (as i have two shiny apps displaying 'live' views).

Maybe someone has better idea how to make it work and pool the data to R constantly (every 5 seconds) from oracle database without encountering this error.

**I have been researching a bit and came across [`pool` package](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html). Is `dbpool()` function gonna solve the problem of maximum open cursors?**

Comment: I don't know about R or ShinyApp but check that each time a cursor is opened you then close it when you're done; this is just good practise. You can also check the open_cursors parameter has been set appropriately.