# The JPA createStoredProcedureQuery throws "ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded" when using Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

I try to call Oracle stored procedure using "createStoredProcedureQuery" of EntityManager by this way:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public void saveMeterVol(Meter meter, Double vol1, Chng chng, User user, Date dt1, Date dt2) {
    StoredProcedureQuery qr = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("mt.P_METER.meter_vol_ins_upd_java");
    qr.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    qr.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    qr.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    qr.registerStoredProcedureParameter(4, Double.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    qr.registerStoredProcedureParameter(5, Date.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    qr.registerStoredProcedureParameter(6, Date.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    qr.registerStoredProcedureParameter(7, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);

    qr.setParameter(2, meter.getId());
    qr.setParameter(3, chng.getId());
    qr.setParameter(4, vol1);
    qr.setParameter(5, dt1);
    qr.setParameter(6, dt2);
    qr.setParameter(7, user.getCd());
    qr.execute();
}
```

When I call this method over 300 times, Oracle fall into exception:
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

As I understand, Java doesn't close Oracle cursor after call my procedure, but I don't understand why?

I tried to do

```
em.close();
```

but it didn't help.

I use:

```
<spring-framework.version>5.0.5.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
<hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

Comment: try to open more cursors `ALTER SYSTEM SET OPEN_CURSORS=1000 SID='*' SCOPE=BOTH;` in your database, read this also, maybe it can help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192592/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded

Comment: This is not solution, according your link: "Cursor leaks are bugs; increasing the number of cursors on the DB simply delays the inevitable failure" It is just temporal solution, if I want to invoke my method more than 1000 times, it will fall to exception again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The default `CallableStatement` handling mechanism

When calling the `execute` method on the JPA `StoredProcedureQuery` or `outputs().getCurrent()` on the Hibernate `ProcedureCall`, Hibernate executes the following actions:

[image: Stored procedure sequence diagram]

Notice that a JDBC `CallableStatement` is prepared and stored in the associated `ProcedureOutputsImpl` object. When calling the `getOutputParameterValue` method, Hibernate will use the underlying `CallableStatement` to fetch the `OUT` parameter.

> For this reason, the underlying JDBC CallableStatement remains open even after executing the stored procedure and fetching the OUT or REF_CURSOR parameters.

Now, by default, the `CallableStatement` is closed upon ending the currently running database transaction, either via calling `commit` or `rollback`.

[image: Entity transaction]

### Closing the JDBC statement as soon as possible

Therefore, to close the JDBC `CallableStatement` as soon as possible, you should call `release` after fetching all the data that you wanted from the stored procedure:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
.createStoredProcedureQuery("count_comments")
.registerStoredProcedureParameter(
    "postId",
    Long.class,
    ParameterMode.IN
)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter(
    "commentCount",
    Long.class,
    ParameterMode.OUT
)
.setParameter("postId", 1L);
 
try {
    query.execute();
     
    Long commentCount = (Long) query
    .getOutputParameterValue("commentCount");
 
    assertEquals(Long.valueOf(2), commentCount);
} finally {
    query.unwrap(ProcedureOutputs.class).release();
}
```

Calling the `release` method on the associated `ProcedureOutputs` object in the `finally` block ensures that the JDBC `CallableStatement` is closed no matter the outcome of the stored procedure call.

### Hibernate 6 onwards

Now, calling `release` manually is a little bit tedious, so I decided to create the [HHH-13215](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13215) Jira issue which, from Hibernate ORM 6 onwards, allows you to rewrite the previous example like this:

```
Long commentCount = doInJPA(entityManager -> {
    try(ProcedureCall query = entityManager
            .createStoredProcedureQuery("count_comments")
            .unwrap(ProcedureCall.class)) {
             
        return (Long) query
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
            "postId",
            Long.class,
            ParameterMode.IN
        )
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
            "commentCount",
            Long.class,
            ParameterMode.OUT
        )
        .setParameter("postId", 1L)
        .getOutputParameterValue("commentCount");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, I read your article. But when implement it to application, I always got `java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Statement` after warning `Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@704e89f9 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(17009)` . I searched google, but can not find any solution. It would be great if you give me some information to solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Eventually I found the solution, I replaced the line

```
qr.execute();
```

with

```
qr.executeUpdate();
```

According documetation: "When executeUpdate is called on a StoredProcedureQuery object, the provider will call execute on an unexecuted stored procedure query followed by getUpdateCount. The results of executeUpdate will be those of getUpdateCount"

But they didn't say anything conserning closing cursors but my method works well now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
int           retValue = -1;
ProcedureCall query    = null;

try {
  query = (ProcedureCall)entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("MyStoredProcedure");

  query
    .setParameter("param1", value1)
    .setParameter("param2", value2)
    .execute();

  retValue = (int)query.getOutputParameterValue("outParam");
} finally {
  query.getOutputs().release();
}
```