# Maximum Cursors exceeded SQLException-- Configuration problem or Cursor leak?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, database-connection, sqlexception

I am calling an SQL procedure through Java. I am getting SQL Exception in the logs while executing my code- 
**java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded**

I had gone through similar questions and tried this-

1. increased open_cursors from 30000 to 40000.
2. closed the statement in try and finally block.

But it did not solve the problem. Is something wrong with my code?

Here is my Java code-

```
public static void buildingHelpContent(String p_id) throws Throwable{
        Connection conn = ExtractHP.getConnection();
        CallableStatement cs = null;
        log.debug("arguments for COMP.Help.build_hp_data  p_id=  "+p_id);
        try {
            cs = conn.prepareCall("{call COMP.Help.build_hp_data(?)}");
            cs.setString(1, p_id);
            cs.execute();
            if(cs!=null)            
                cs.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log = ExtractHP.getLogger();
            log.debug("!!! Java Exception !!!\n");
            log.error("Exception while executing the procedure for ID ...."+ p_id, e);          
        }
        finally{
            if(cs!=null)
                cs.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume the issue is in your sql code.

Comment: Now that you've added a `close` call to the `finally` block, I suggest you remove the `close` code from the `try` block. And as @user7294900 says, add `if(conn!=null) conn.close();` to the `finally` block.

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192592/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded) might help you

Comment: Hi @BobJarvis I have added conn.close(); in finally block. But getting below exception now:   java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the connection, you can use `try-with-resources` block (without `finally`):

```
    log.debug("arguments for COMP.Help.build_hp_data  p_id=  "+p_id);
    try (Connection conn = ExtractHP.getConnection();
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call COMP.Help.build_hp_data(?)}")){
```

In java 6 also close connection in `finally`  :

```
finally{
        if(cs!=null)
            cs.close();
        if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this code is very old and is written in Java 1.6. Cannot use try-with-resources.

Comment: @RichaSharma see my updated answer, add `conn.close();` to `finally`

Comment: +1 for your suggestion @user7294900. After adding the conn.close() in finally block, now I am getting a new exception:  java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection  Is there any problem in the Java code with Throw and Throwable?

Comment: @RichaSharma I suggest you open a new question with code inside `ExtractHP.getConnection()`