# Oracle -> Azure sql. Maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: oracle, azure-sql-database, freetds

I'm using freeTDS driver to make connection between Oracle and Azure sql. I've created db link.
The problem is that when i make big query which are using this dblink (like 10 joins) it returns me error:

```
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
ORA-02063: preceding line from AZURE_DB_LINK.
```

I tried to modify maximum open cursors in my db - it didn't work.
I tried modify gateway configuration file like:

```
HS_OPEN_CURSORS=100
HS_FDS_FETCH_ROWS=1000
```

But still it doesn't work. Do you have any idea how i can resolve that problem?

Comment: check this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192592/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded) if it helped.

Comment: This thread didn't help me. I don't have problem with my db. Probably this is problem with driver or remote db.