# Oracle 12c MAX statements in Java Database Connectivity (JDBC)

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connection, odbc, statements

I have worked on the ODBC side of database driver development and have a good understanding of Connections and statements in that space. With JDBC, I am a little at a loss when trying to get similar information on it. I am looking for some thing similar to the following for Oracle 12c and need help with it.

The following is a good list of System limits and defaults for TimesTen, example it lists the "Maximum number of prepared PL/SQL statements per connection." has a default number.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTREF/limit.htm#TTREF455

With Oracle 12c I see some information similar to this where they say this number varies based on the number of caches statements. Is there a document that has a list of the system limits for the Oracle 12C version as well.

Sample code to call some of the metadata for information does not return much either (code sample below)

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd;
// connect to the database

 try{
        dbmd = g_dbConn.getMetaData();
        System.out.println(dbmd.getDatabaseProductName());
        System.out.println(dbmd.getDatabaseProductVersion());
        System.out.println(dbmd.getDriverName());
        System.out.println(dbmd.getDriverVersion());
        System.out.println(dbmd.getCatalogs());
        //System.out.println(dbmd.getCatalogTerm());
        System.out.println(dbmd.getMaxConnections());
        System.out.println(dbmd.getMaxStatementLength());
        System.out.println(dbmd.getMaxStatements());
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

--------------------- O U T P U T ------------------------
Oracle

Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

Oracle JDBC driver

12.1.0.2.0

oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@f8c1ddd

0

65535

0

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question : Is there a document that has a list of the system limits for the Oracle 12C version as well like the one given below.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTREF/limit.htm#TTREF455

With the Oracle JDBC driver, does it support more than one statement per connection? If so, is there a parameter /setting that can be refereed to for the value or maybe an API call that will return this value setting in a database. 

Any information on this would be of great help.

Comment: Asking for external resources like that is off-topic.

Comment: is there a parameter /setting that can be refereed to for the value or maybe an API call that will return this value setting in a database

Comment: Found a document with some information on this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790476/single-connection-with-oracle?rq=1